# How do I compare non-zero values over multiple 2D numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have two 2D arrays filled with random integers. 
I want the first array to retain all indices with values leq 5, and the second array to retain all indices with values leq 6. For simplicity, all other indices can be set to zero.

```
table1 = np.array(([1,3],[5,7]))
table2  = np.array(([2,4],[6,8]))

print table1
print table2 ,'\n'

table1_tol_i = np.where(table1[:,:] > 5)
table1[table1_tol_i] = 0
print table1 

table2_tol_i = np.where(table2[:,:] > 4)
table2[table2_tol_i] = 0
print table2, '\n'

[[1 3]
 [5 7]]
[[2 4]
 [6 8]] 

[[1 3]
 [5 0]]
[[2 4]
 [0 0]]
```

I then want to retain only the indices where both tables have non-zero values. I want

```
[[1 3]
 [0 0]]
[[2 4]
 [0 0]]
```

I tried the following but it doesn't give me what I want

```
nonzero_i = (np.where(table1 != 0) and (np.where(table2 != 0 )))
print table1[nonzero_i]
print table2[nonzero_i]

[1 3]
[2 4]
```

Comment: Your description is accurate about what I am trying to achieve but don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *are* retaining only the indices where both tables have non-zero values - that's why when you index into `table1` and `table2` with `nonzero_i`, you return only the first row (which contains only non-zero values).

This logic could be expressed more simply by constructing a [boolean index array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays):

```
# boolean array that is True wherever both table1 & table2 are nonzero
valid = (table1 != 0) & (table2 != 0)

# or alternatively:
# valid = np.logical_and(table1, table2)
```

You could use this to index directly into `table1` and `table2`.

---

It seems that what you *actually* want to do is to assign a value of 0 to any location where either `table1` or `table2` is 0.

If you want a copy, you could use the `np.where(condition, val_where_true, val_where_false)` syntax of [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
print(repr(np.where(valid, table1, 0)))
# array([[1, 3],
#        [0, 0]])

print(repr(np.where(valid, table2, 0)))
# array([[2, 4],
#        [0, 0]])
```

Or if you wanted to modify `table1` and `table2` in place, you could do

```
table1[~valid] = 0

table2[~valid] = 0
```

(`~` is the "bitwise not" operator, which inverts the boolean index array).

Answer (score 0):

Get all indices where table 1 is 0:

`table1_zeros = np.where(table1[:,:] == 0)`

Get all indices where table 2 is 0:

`table2_zeros = np.where(table2[:,:] == 0)`

Set values on both tables to 0:

```
table1[table1_zeros] = 0
table1[table2_zeros] = 0
table2[table1_zeros] = 0
table2[table2_zeros] = 0
```

You could also do this in one step by using `tableX_tol_i` in place of `tableX_zeros`.

Answer (score -1):

```
table1 = np.array(([1,3],[5,7]))
table2  = np.array(([2,4],[6,8]))
table3  = np.zeros((2,2))
for k in range(0,2):
    for j in range(0,2):
        if table1[k][j] > 5:
            table1[k][j] = 0
        if table1[k][j] <= 5:
            table1[k][j] = table1[k][j]
        if table2[k][j] > 6:
            table2[k][j] = 0
        if table2[k][j] <= 6:
            table2[k][j] = table2[k][j]
x=0
y=0
for k in range(0,2):
    for j in range(0,2):
        if table1[k][j] != 0:
            table3[x,y] = table1[k][j] 
            x = x+1
x=0
y=1
for k in range(0,2):
    for j in range(0,2):
        if table2[k][j] != 0:
            table3[x,y] = table2[k][j] 
            x = x+1   
print (table3)
```

I think it is the simplest way, what you want. You can modify the code, if your array size changes.