# What's a good way of setting most elements of an ndarray to zero?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I've got an `ndarray` with, say, 10,000 rows and 75 columns, and another one with the same number of rows and, say, 3 columns. The second one has integer values.

I want to end up with an array of 10,000 rows and 75 columns with all the elements set to zero except the elements in each row indexed by the values in the corresponding row of the second array.

So starting with `z_array` and `i_array`, I want to end up with `a_array`

```
>>> z_array
array([[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]])
>>> i_array
array([[0, 2],
       [3, 1],
       [1, 4],
       [2, 3]])
>>> a_array
array([[10,  0, 12,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 11,  0, 13,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 11,  0,  0, 14,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 12, 13,  0,  0]])
```

I can see two ways of approaching this: either start with an array full of zeros and copy across the relevant elements from `z_array`; or start with `z_array` and set all the irrelevant elements to zero. Note that the number of irrelevant elements is typically much, much larger than the number of relevant elements.

Either way, is there a good way of doing the multiple assignments, or do I simply have to loop through them? Or is there a third approach?

I'm wondering if I can use [`numpy.ufunc.at`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) somehow?
I can see how to get a list of indexes for the relevant elements, for example

```
>>> index_list = [[i, val] for (i, x) in enumerate(i_array) for val in x ]
index_list
[[0, 0], [0, 2], [1, 3], [1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 4], [3, 2], [3, 3]]
```

And there's a slightly more complex way to get them for the irrelevant elements. But these lists would be big!!

Comment: Consider using mask arrays https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/maskedarray.generic.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for something similar to `np.put_along_axis`

Taking the example you have there if you run: `np.put_along_axis(z_array, i_array, 0, axis=1)`

```
z_array = [[ 0 11  0 13 14 15]
 [10  0 12  0 14 15]
 [10  0 12 13  0 15]
 [10 11  0  0 14 15]]
```

The output is the opposite of what you want.

To get what you want, create a copy of `z_array` as `a_array`. Then, compare these matrices and keep the values where the elements of `z_array` are non-zero.

```
a_array = copy.copy(z_array)
np.put_along_axis(z_array, i_array, 0, axis=1)
a_array[(z_array != 0)] = 0
```

This gives the output you expected:

```
a_array = [[10  0 12  0  0  0]
 [ 0 11  0 13  0  0]
 [ 0 11  0  0 14  0]
 [ 0  0 12 13  0  0]]
```

---

`np.put_along_axis` [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.put_along_axis.html)

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34644625/12040795) for more options for combining matrics (`np.where`)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [masked arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/maskedarray.generic.html)

```
import numpy as np

def mask_array(z_array, i_array):
    ROWS, COLS = np.shape(z_array)

    # Fill in the mask
    mask = np.zeros((ROWS, COLS))
    for i in range(ROWS):
        np.add.at(mask[i,:], i_array[i], 1)
    mask = mask > 0
    mask = ~mask

    m_array = np.ma.array(z_array, mask=mask, fill_value = 0)
    return np.ma.filled(m_array)

a_array = mask_array(z_array, i_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

To tell apart elements of *z_array*, I defined it as:

```
array([[ 10,  11,  12,  13,  14,  15],
       [110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115],
       [210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215],
       [310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315]])
```

Then one of possible solutions is to create an array filled with zeroes, using
*zeros_like* and then run a loop based on *ndenumerate* method:

```
result = np.zeros_like(z_array)
for (r, c), x in np.ndenumerate(i_array):
    result[r, x] = z_array[r, x]
```

For my (changed) source data, the result is:

```
array([[ 10,   0,  12,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0, 111,   0, 113,   0,   0],
       [  0, 211,   0,   0, 214,   0],
       [  0,   0, 312, 313,   0,   0]])
```